is possible using ng-jhipster with angular 11?
this is my json Package:
  "dependencies": {
    "3": "^2.1.0",
    "-": "0.0.1",
    "@akveo/ng2-completer": "^9.0.1",
    "@angular/animations": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/localize": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "^11.2.13",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^11.2.13",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "^11.2.14",
    "@ctrl/ngx-codemirror": "^4.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.8.2",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.15.4",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.36",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.4",
    "@nebular/bootstrap": "^7.0.5",
    "@nebular/eva-icons": "^7.0.5",
    "@nebular/theme": "^7.0.5",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^9.1.3",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^6.1.0",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/core": "^5.1.2",
    "@ngx-loading-bar/router": "^5.1.2",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^13.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^6.0.0",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.149",
    "angular-pipes": "^10.0.0",
    "bootstrap": "4.5.0",
    "classlist.js": "1.1.20150312",
    "codemirror": "^5.59.4",
    "cookieconsent": "^3.1.1",
    "core-js": "2.5.1",
    "eva-icons": "^1.1.3",
    "ionicons": "2.0.1",
    "jquery": "^1.9.1",
    "list": "^2.0.19",
    "lodash": "^4.17.15",
    "moment": "2.27.0",
    "ng-jhipster": "^0.16.0",
    "ng2-completer": "^9.0.1",
    "ng2-smart-table": "^1.6.0",
    "ngx-cookie": "4.0.2",
    "ngx-cookie-service": "10.1.1",
    "ngx-cookieconsent": "^2.2.3",
    "ngx-currency": "^2.3.3",
    "ngx-filesize": "^2.0.16",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "9.0.0",
    "ngx-timeline-vertical": "^1.0.3",
    "ngx-webstorage": "6.0.0",
    "npm": "^10.7.0",
    "roboto-fontface": "^0.10.0",
    "rxjs": "6.6.2",
    "swagger-ui-dist": "^5.17.2",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^11.2.19",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^11.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "^11.2.14",
    "@ngtools/webpack": "^11.2.19",
    "@openapitools/openapi-generator-cli": "1.0.13-4.3.1",
    "@sia/generator-jhipster-easylake": "0.0.1",
    "@types/jest": "26.0.3",
    "@types/node": "13.13.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "2.30.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin-tslint": "2.30.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "2.30.0",
    "autoprefixer": "9.8.4",
    "base-href-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "browser-sync": "^3.0.2",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "^2.3.0",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "6.0.2",
    "css-loader": "3.6.0",
    "eslint": "6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-jhipster": "0.0.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "6.11.0",
    "eslint-loader": "4.0.2",
    "file-loader": "6.0.0",
    "friendly-errors-webpack-plugin": "1.7.0",
    "generator-jhipster": "^8.4.0",
    "html-loader": "1.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "4.3.0",
    "husky": "4.2.5",
    "jest": "26.1.0",
    "jest-date-mock": "1.0.8",
    "jest-junit": "11.0.1",
    "jest-preset-angular": "8.2.1",
    "jest-sonar-reporter": "2.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "^15.2.2",
    "merge-jsons-webpack-plugin": "1.0.21",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.9.0",
    "moment-locales-webpack-plugin": "1.2.0",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.3",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "prettier": "2.0.5",
    "rimraf": "3.0.2",
    "sass": "1.26.9",
    "sass-loader": "8.0.2",
    "simple-progress-webpack-plugin": "1.1.2",
    "style-loader": "1.2.1",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "3.0.6",
    "thread-loader": "2.1.3",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.6",
    "ts-loader": "7.0.5",
    "tslint": "6.1.2",
    "typescript": "^4.0.8",
    "webpack": "^5.91.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "3.8.0",
    "webpack-cli": "3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^5.0.4",
    "webpack-merge": "4.2.2",
    "webpack-notifier": "^1.15.0",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "5.1.3",
    "write-file-webpack-plugin": "4.5.1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=14.17.6"
  },

I update my angular version to 10 from 11 but i can use ng-jhipster
with npm list i receive this error:
**
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/common@^10.0.0, required by ng-jhipster@0.16.0**
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/common@^10.0.0, required by ng2-smart-table@1.7.2
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/common@^10.0.5, required by ngx-cookie-service@10.1.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/common@^9.0.7, required by ngx-timeline-vertical@1.0.3
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/common@^10.0.0, required by ngx-webstorage@6.0.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@^10.0.0, required by ng-jhipster@0.16.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@^10.0.0, required by ng2-smart-table@1.7.2
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@^10.0.5, required by ngx-cookie-service@10.1.1
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@^9.0.7, required by ngx-timeline-vertical@1.0.3
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/core@^10.0.0, required by ngx-webstorage@6.0.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/forms@^10.0.0, required by ng-jhipster@0.16.0
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/forms@^10.0.0, required by ng2-smart-table@1.7.2
npm ERR! peer dep missing: @angular/router@^10.0.0, required by ng-jhipster@0.16.0
